# How to write code for get photo from photo library in android?

Tags: android

I want code for get the photo from photo library and add that photo into profile in android.

Answer (score 3):

You can launch a specific Intent to get a photo from the device.

First, define a constant for Intent result code such as:

```
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_CODE = 0;
```

Then, when necessary, call the Intent:

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent();
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*"); // to pick only images
photoPickerIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PICTURE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_CODE);
```

Finally, implement [Activity.onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29) method to get the URI of the selected image:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case SELECT_PICTURE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_CODE:
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            // deal with it
            break;
        default:
            // deal with it
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

After, you can deal with this Uri and with [Contacts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Contacts.html) and [Profile](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Profile.html) API. Maybe operations described on this documentation could help:

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.html#PHOTO maybe as the first parameter of [withValue](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProviderOperation.Builder.html#withValue%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) method on [newUpdate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProviderOperation.html#newUpdate%28android.net.Uri%29)